# Updating WSO2 API Manager Registry.xml.j2 file in EKS Environment

Tags: wso2, amazon-eks, wso2-api-manager

So We are facing some issues with Solr Search query while loading APIs in WSO2 APIM publisher and devportal for which I need to add a regular expression property in <APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/registry.xml.j2 file but we are using EKS Based Environment and don't have any mapping for this file in our Deployments.

And I know any changes I do directly in file via vi editor will be lost once pod is restarted and I think a restart will surely be required for changes to reflect in Registry.xml file.

Can Someone help whats the best way make changes in this file and persist it after pod restart.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't just change the file inside the pod as it requires the server restart. Here are the available options.

1. Use a configmap to mount the file

You can use a configmap in K8s for the file and then mount that configmap to the deployment. It applies to the all the available pods.

2. Update the docker image

You can also update the docker image if it permits. You can add this file to the docker image.

First option is preferred.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but was confused. Thanks @Pubci for clarifying, much appreciated.